# Python: Making sense of references

Tags: python, numpy

I understand basic python references like the difference between a+=b and a=a+b, but this confuses me.

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
arr2 = arr1[0]
arr2 is arr1[0] #returns False, when I expect True
arr1[0] = [7,8,9]
arr2 #[7,8,9], when I expect [0,1,2] since the 'is' returned False
```

What's going on here?

Comment: This seems to be some funny machinations on Numpy's part. Normal lists would work as you expect.

Comment: It's kind of a requirement. Numpy arrays are conceptually just chunks of memory. It would likely be possible to have the *actual* integer value stored in the same bit of memory, but it would cause havoc when that immutable int is mutated by writing to `arr1[0]`.

Comment: @HenryGomersall `arr1[0]` and `arr2` aren't integers, they're Numpy {arrays,views,somethings}.

Comment: @delnan Yeah, I just noticed (cheers!)... so... `arr1[0]` is a view of a bit of memory, not the bit of memory itself. When you do `arr1[0]` you create a new view of the same bit of memory. This means `is` fails, but you can modify the same chunk of memory through each view.

Answer (score 8):

When you index the numpy array, you create a new view (which is itself a numpy array). This is a different object, so `is` fails, but it's a view of the same piece of honestly-actually-on-the-hardware memory. When you modify that view, you therefore modify that bit of memory of which there may be another view.

Edit: You can actually see the start address of the memory associated with a numpy array by inspecting the `ctypes.data` attribute of the array.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr1 = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

In [3]: arr2 = arr1[0]

In [4]: arr2.ctypes.data
Out[4]: 39390224

In [5]: arr1[0].ctypes.data
Out[5]: 39390224
```

The same!

Comment: This is probably correct, but could we get some details? E.g. a chunk of the numpy code that actually does this? I can't seem to find it in the source

Comment: But, that's what numpy arrays *are* - well defined chunks of memory. Essentially, numpy is a lovely pythonic interface to a very low level thing.

Comment: I'm talking about the creation of the views - aren't *those* just Python objects?

Comment: @voithos Of course. Is your question why new views of the same memory are different objects? That's the only sensible thing to do. It's not really the job of numpy to cache every view that is ever created lest the user want the same precise object again but lacked the foresight to write that into the code.

Comment: Just to clarify the last comment. Assigning a created array to a new variable means that new variable *is* the same object. So `arr3 = arr1` followed by `arr3 is arr1` would return `True`. It's when *new* views are created (by indexing an existing array) that a new object is created.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to check whether two numpy arrays point to the same data, use the `base` attribute. From your example:

```
>>> arr1 = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> arr2 = arr1[0]
>>> arr1
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> arr1.base # arr1 is a view of the array before reshaping!
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> arr2.base
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> arr2.base is arr1
True
```

Starting with numpy 1.7 `base` drills all the way down to the original array. From the release notes:

> The `.base` attribute on ndarrays, which is used on views to ensure that the
>   underlying array owning the memory is not deallocated prematurely, now
>   collapses out references when you have a view-of-a-view. For example::

```
a = np.arange(10)
b = a[1:]
c = b[1:]
```

> In numpy 1.6, `c.base` is `b`, and `c.base.base` is `a`. In numpy 1.7,
>   `c.base` is `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the `is`, `=` and `==` operators.

- `is` does identity checks. Use it to see if two variables actually point to the *same object* and not just have the same value
- `=` is the assignment operator. It *assigns* a value to a variable (or slice, as in your case).
- `==` is the *equality* operator. It checks if two object have the same semantic value.

so in your case:

```
arr2 == arr[0] # now should return True
```

Numpy seems to create new objects when you read values from an array. So every time you read, a new object is created. So two reads generate not the same object, so `is` gives `False` as result.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `arr2` later gets changed when he assigns to `arr1`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> arr1 = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> arr1
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> arr2 = arr1[0]
>>> arr2
array([0, 1, 2])
```

So yes, `arr1[0]` and `arr2` are equal. However,

```
>>> arr2 is arr1[0]
False
```

because is is not the tool to compare ndarrays. With `is`, you check if `arr1[0]` and `arr2` are the same object, which is not. Try with `==`, you will get

```
>>> arr2 == arr1[0]
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

or using `numpy.equal(t1,t2)`

```
>>> np.equal(arr2, arr1[0])
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Then you want to have a single boolean answer to your equality test, do

```
>>> (np.equal(arr2, arr1[0])).all()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The ‘is‘ operator compares the identity of two objects; the id() function returns an integer representing its identity (currently implemented as its address).

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

For an example,

```
a = 1, b = 1
a is b
Out[26]:True

id(a)
Out[27]:37470472L

id(b)
Out[27]:37470472L

id(1)
Out[27]:37470472L
```

All three have same identity. But,

```
a = [1]
b = [1]
a is b
Out[26]:False

id(a)
Out[37]:142781064L

id(b)
Out[38]:142780616L
```

Therefore, same thing happens in arrays. They don't have the same identity.

Comment: Interestingly, it's actually possible to fool oneself by inspecting the `id()` of an object, as happened once to me yesterday when I was playing around this question. If you inspect the id of the view (with `id(arr1[0])`) and then assign `arr2 = arr1[0]` and inspect its id (with `id(arr2)`), it's perfectly possible that those ids are the same. The `arr1[0]` was created, its id found, and then immediately it went out of scope, so the memory (which is how CPython assigns ids) could be reallocated to a new object. I take from this that you should *only* compare the ids of objects in scope.